# Why 0 pending notifications

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, localnotification, flutter-local-notification

I am using [flutter_local_notification V 5.00+3](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/versions/5.0.0+3) and call flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.pendingNotificationRequests()

always returns 0 (zero) , even if I execute

FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().show

twice and do not click the notification, leaving the notification, the code is shown below and is taken from the example with simple modification of adding idOfMsg as **id of message**.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/subjects.dart';

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

/// Streams are created so that app can respond to notification-related events
/// since the plugin is initialised in the `main` function
final BehaviorSubject<ReceivedNotification> didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject =
    BehaviorSubject<ReceivedNotification>();

final BehaviorSubject<String?> selectNotificationSubject =
    BehaviorSubject<String?>();

const MethodChannel platform =
    MethodChannel('dexterx.dev/flutter_local_notifications_example');

class ReceivedNotification {
  ReceivedNotification({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.body,
    required this.payload,
  });

  final int id;
  final String? title;
  final String? body;
  final String? payload;
}

String? selectedNotificationPayload;

/// IMPORTANT: running the following code on its own won't work as there is
/// setup required for each platform head project.
///
/// Please download the complete example app from the GitHub repository where
/// all the setup has been done
Future<void> main() async {
  // needed if you intend to initialize in the `main` function
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
  String initialRoute = HomePage.routeName;
  if (notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false) {
    selectedNotificationPayload = notificationAppLaunchDetails!.payload;
    initialRoute = SecondPage.routeName;
  }

  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

  /// Note: permissions aren't requested here just to demonstrate that can be
  /// done later
  final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
      IOSInitializationSettings(
          requestAlertPermission: false,
          requestBadgePermission: false,
          requestSoundPermission: false,
          onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
              (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
            didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.add(ReceivedNotification(
                id: id, title: title, body: body, payload: payload));
          });
  const MacOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsMacOS =
      MacOSInitializationSettings(
          requestAlertPermission: false,
          requestBadgePermission: false,
          requestSoundPermission: false);
  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
      macOS: initializationSettingsMacOS);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
    }
    selectedNotificationPayload = payload;
    selectNotificationSubject.add(payload);
  });
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: initialRoute,
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        HomePage.routeName: (_) => HomePage(notificationAppLaunchDetails),
        SecondPage.routeName: (_) => SecondPage(selectedNotificationPayload)
      },
    ),
  );
}

class PaddedElevatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const PaddedElevatedButton({
    required this.buttonText,
    required this.onPressed,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String buttonText;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 8),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          child: Text(buttonText),
        ),
      );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage(
    this.notificationAppLaunchDetails, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static const String routeName = '/';

  final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails;

  bool get didNotificationLaunchApp =>
      notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _requestPermissions();
    _configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject();
    _configureSelectNotificationSubject();
  }

  void _configureSelectNotificationSubject() {
    selectNotificationSubject.stream.listen((String? payload) async {
      await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/secondPage');
    });
  }

  void _requestPermissions() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
  }

  void _configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject() {
    didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.stream
        .listen((ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
      await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
          title: receivedNotification.title != null
              ? Text(receivedNotification.title!)
              : null,
          content: receivedNotification.body != null
              ? Text(receivedNotification.body!)
              : null,
          actions: <Widget>[
            CupertinoDialogAction(
              isDefaultAction: true,
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
                await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        SecondPage(receivedNotification.payload),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Ok'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.close();
    selectNotificationSubject.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 8),
                      child: Text(
                          'Tap on a notification when it appears to trigger'
                          ' navigation'),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 8),
                      child: Text.rich(
                        TextSpan(
                          children: <InlineSpan>[
                            const TextSpan(
                              text: 'Did notification launch app? ',
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: '${widget.didNotificationLaunchApp}',
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    if (widget.didNotificationLaunchApp)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 8),
                        child: Text.rich(
                          TextSpan(
                            children: <InlineSpan>[
                              const TextSpan(
                                text: 'Launch notification payload: ',
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              TextSpan(
                                text: widget
                                    .notificationAppLaunchDetails!.payload,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                    PaddedElevatedButton(
                      buttonText: 'Show 1 plain notification with payload',
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await _showNotification(1);
                      },
                    ),

                    PaddedElevatedButton(
                      buttonText: 'Show 2 plain notification with payload',
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await _showNotification(2);
                      },
                    ),

                    PaddedElevatedButton(
                      buttonText: 'Check pending notifications',
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await _checkPendingNotificationRequests();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  Future<void> _showNotification(int idOfMsg) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            ticker: 'ticker');
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        idOfMsg, 'plain title'+ idOfMsg.toString(), 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'item x' + idOfMsg.toString());
  }

  Future<void> _cancelNotification() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(0);
  }

  Future<void> _checkPendingNotificationRequests() async {
    final List<PendingNotificationRequest> pendingNotificationRequests =
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.pendingNotificationRequests();
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
        content:
            Text('${pendingNotificationRequests.length} pending notification '
                'requests'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: const Text('OK'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _cancelAllNotifications() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondPage(
    this.payload, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static const String routeName = '/secondPage';

  final String? payload;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SecondPageState();
}

class SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  String? _payload;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _payload = widget.payload;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Second Screen ${_payload ?? ''}  with payload: '),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Text('Go back!'),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Please help so that I can get list of notifications that are still not clicked by user nor cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pendingNotificationRequests is for scheduled notification that has not yet appeared in notification panel.

getActiveNotifications is for notifications that are available in notification panel.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that was present in the example itself

```
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!
          .getActiveNotifications();
```